# jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to select a class in my javascript and change one of its property. 
but since that class is being used with different divs, I need to change the property of the class I hover upon only and not the other ones. is that possible?

the html structure looks like this:

```
<div class="home_linkbox_href"><a href=""><div class="home_linkbox">
                    <h1>/h1>
                    <h2></h2>
                </div></a></div>
```

the javascript:

```
$(".home_linkbox_href a").hover(function(){
    //alert("u did it...");
    $(".home_linkbox_href a .home_linkbox").css("background-color", "#ffe500");

    },
    function(){
        $(".home_linkbox").css("background-color", "#000");
});
```

can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify `this` as the context for the selector, which will find matches only in the currently hovered element:

```
$(".home_linkbox_href a").hover(function(){
    //alert("u did it...");
    $(".home_linkbox", this).css("background-color", "#ffe500");

    },
    function(){
        $(".home_linkbox", this).css("background-color", "#000");
});
```

Comment: i used $(this) before. But .find() did the trick. thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you would use $(this).

```
$(".home_linkbox_href a").hover(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "#ffe500");
    $(this).attr("href", "http://www.google.com");
    },
    function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "#000");
});
```

Comment: `$(this)` would give you the `<a>` element. OP wants the `.home_linkbox` that is a child of the `<a>`

Comment: @patrick Yes, you are right.  I didn't read OP's code close enough.  Originally he was changing the href too, so I assumed it was the `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".home_linkbox_href").find("a").hover(
  function(){
    $(this).siblings(".home_linkbox").css("background-color", "#ffe500");
  },

  function(){
    $(this).siblings(".home_linkbox").css("background-color", "#000");
  }
);
```